# Calling a web service with a certificate from WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I was supplied a WSDL file and XSD for connecting to a web service. I have imported these into a WCF project for use from a WCF service. This part is all working fine.

My problem comes in when trying to figure out how to call the web service from my WCF service using a certificate (which I have). At present my binding object is BasicHttpBinding. I am (almost) sure that this should be BasocHttpsBinding instead.

I think I may need to configure the binding object passed to the constructor of the connection of the web service. I have searched all over the internet but have been unable to find a reference or an example to help in my endeavours. I would appreciate any help in this regard.

An example with source code would be first prize. A decent reference would help too.

Comment: We have used a wsHttpBinding for our services requiring a certificate. However we used TransportWithMessageCredential, which uses a certificate for the ssl, and a custom authenticator for the credential part. Do you get any error requesting resources at the web service?

Comment: Not yet ... I am still struggling to associate the certificate with the WSHttpBinding object. Once I can get this working and attempt a connection to the service will I be able to get an error message. I really need a code sample just to see how to configure this. At the moment it is trial and error ... actually at this time it is just error!

Comment: Could it be the client -> endpoint -> identity element help you? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733130(v=vs.110).aspx) - Check out the paragraph "Specifying Identity at the Client"

Comment: Post the code that youve created and its error.